# MongoDB Partial Index not working with OR expression

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database-design

I have a MongoDB collection with documents having fields as we would see below. I'm trying to build a partial index with an expression that would be used in my filter queries.

Here's the `Partial Index` creation command

```
db.reviews.createIndex(
  {
    catalog_id: 1,
    product_id: 1,
    score: -1,
    created_at: -1
  },
  {
    name: "reviews_only_fetch_by_catalog_product",
    partialFilterExpression: {
      $or: [
        { comments: { $exists: true } },
        { images: { $exists: true } },
        { videos: { $exists: true } }
      ]
    }
  }
)
```

When I run the below query, I was expecting the partial index getting leveraged as the filter expression is a subset of partial index expression.

```
{
  $and: [
    {
      catalog_id: '100'
    },
    {
      $or: [
        {
          comments: {
            $exists: true
          }
        },
        {
          images: {
            $exists: true
          }
        },
        {
          videos: {
            $exists: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But surprisingly, the `explain plan` makes a `COLLSCAN` instead of using the index. Why would the `$or` filter that is exactly as defined in the index definition not work for the query?

While the below query is able to leverage the index.

```
{
  catalog_id: '100',
  comments: {
    $exists: true
  }
}
```

MongoDB version - `6.0.4`

Comment: Try using explain with the allPlansExecution option to see what queries were considered, and how each performed.